# Derive a new column based on current month - 3 months

Tags: sql, databricks-sql

I need a query to derive the logic for the below scenario.

I need to display the data in below format. Below column is based on Fiscal Year which will starts from Oct and ends in Sep. For ex. 2023 fiscal year starts from 2022-Oct to 2023-Sep.

I have to display the month closed or not. If month closed the Y else N. Logic to find the month closed or not would be "**last 3 months of a fiscal year will be closed in next fiscal year**"

Sample Data.

[image]
For ex. In June, March month will be closed as Y and remaining months will be N.

I have tried to compare the current with months between but is not giving actual result.

Comment: Can you provide your original sample data? It's not clear what the original structure is that you are trying to convert to this display.

Comment: Hi @Error_2646

I have updated the sample data. I need to derive 13th row as per the above requirement. Last 3 months of fiscal year will be closed in next fiscal year. Basically it should check last 3 months with current month and mark  Y or N accordingly.

Comment: Is that truly how the data exists in your table, with the column data types a hodgepodge of numeric and string? If so, it'd be a good idea not to do that. In any case, have or tried just greatest(Jul, Aug, Sep) as closed_3_months_before_year_end? This would of course only be valid for your last row (Food 13. Month Closed Y/N). A CASE would work in general, but a bit more typing.